# jqgrid filtertoolbar not displaying filter operators like (==, !=, >=....)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to have a filter toolbar on jqgrid. I can see the filter toolbar but I can't change the filter operator (operators menu doesn't appear on grid). and the default search operator is "Equal" while I want it to be "Contains".

the library is downloaded from: [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)

and here's my BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Admin").Include(
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/pages.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/widgets.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/pixel-admin.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/rtl.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/themes.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jquery-ui.1.10.4.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/clockpicker/clockpicker.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jstree.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jqgrid/searchFilter.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap-ui.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid.css",
                      "~/Content/Admin/css/jqgrid/ui.multiselect.css"
                      ));


bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Admin").Include(
               "~/Scripts/Admin/bootstrap.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/jquery-1.8.2.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/jqgrid/jquery.contextmenu.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/jqgrid/jquery.searchFilter.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/i18n/grid.locale-en.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/i18n/grid.locale-fa.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/clockpicker.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/highcharts.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/jstree.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/pixel-admin.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/Admin/Base64Helper.js"
               ));
```

grid setup:

```
$("#grvList").jqGrid({
                loadError: function (error) {
                    var responseTitle = $(error.responseText).filter('title').get(0);
                    $.growl.error({ message: responseTitle.innerHTML });
                },
                loadComplete: function (data) {

                },
                onSelectRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
                    fillSelectedRow(rowid);
                },

                direction: dir,
                url: '@Url.Action("getList","Countries")',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                jsonReader: {
                    root: 'rows',
                    total: 'total',
                    page: 'page',
                    records: 'records',
                    cell: 'cell',
                    id: 'Id',
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                colNames: ['Id', 'Title', 'Code', 'Abbrevation', 'State'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', label: 'Id', key: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Title', label: '@Res.Public.Countries.Title', sorttype: 'string', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] } },
                { name: 'Code', label: '@Res.Public.Countries.Code', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'lt', 'gt', 'ge'] } },
                { name: 'Abbrevation', label: '@Res.Public.Countries.Abb', search:false },
                {
                    name: 'State', label: '@Res.Public.Countries.State',search:false, formatter: function genderformatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        if (cellvalue === 0) {
                            return "@Res.Public.Admin.Active";
                        }
                        else if (cellvalue === 1) {
                            return "@Res.Public.Admin.Inactive";
                        }
                        else
                            return "";
                    }
                }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                sortname: 'Title',
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                pager: '#pager',
                loadonce: true,
                height: "auto",
                gridview: true,
                width: null,
                autowidth: true
            });
            jQuery("#grvList").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn', searchOperators: true, searchOnEnter: false, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] } });
```

here's the output:
[image: grid output]

where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can update the order of the script inclusions and some you can omit like `jquery.searchFilter.js`. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install

Comment: I followed the instruction on the link but this is not solving my problem!

Comment: Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? I suppose that you should **remove** `jquery.searchFilter.js` and `searchFilter.css` and to include `jquery.contextmenu.js` only if you really use the plugin.

Comment: I've downloaded the library from here:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6
I don't know which version is it. and I tried removing searchFilter.js and .css and I added context menu. nothing again!
by the way I also edited jquery.jqGrid.js filterToolbar function and set the defaultSeach to "cn" but I still can't filter data by 'contain' operator

Comment: @Oleg after inspecting elements of the page I found this <ul> but it's empty. why is that?
<ul id="sopt_menu" class="ui-search-menu modal-content ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" tabindex="0" style="font-size:11px;left:839px;top:681px;"></ul>

Comment: Sorry, but you should not jump from one way to another. About context menu and other: I mean just **don't just include all file which you found**. I use **free jqGrid** fork, which I develop after changing license agreement of trirand (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). The page http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 is misunderstandable. You download here Guriddo jqGrid JS, thus you should read http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334 for the prices if you use it. About your main proble. I created the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kvtrtzc5/, which uses **free jqGrid**. Try it.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I'll give it a try

Comment: @Oleg I used free jqGrid and the problem is now solved. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean just don't just include all file which you found. I use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop after changing license agreement of trirand (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). The page http://trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 is misunderstandable. You download here **Guriddo jqGrid JS**, thus you should read http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334 for the prices if you use it. About your main problem. I created the demo jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kvtrtzc5, which uses free jqGrid. Try it. I see no problem which you describe.